# Local variable to a package

Tags: macros, packages, package-writing, scoping

I am defining my own latex package `mypackage.sty`. How to define a local command such that: `mycommand`

- If `mycommand` is already defined elsewhere it will be locally redefined just inside the package
- If `mycommand` is not already defined, it will be locally defined just inside the package, and unavailable from outside of the package

Same question with lengths that would be locally defined using `\newlength` and `\setlength`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with *inside* and *outside* the package? The usual solution would be to use internal names like `\vincentspackage@mycommand`. But those would usually also be available anywhere else unless you put your package code into a group (which is usually not done).

Comment: there is no local scope related to the package loading, just prefix your names with some internal prefix, allocations such as `\newlength` have to be global.

Comment: This is indeed a problem, and the source of many package conflicts that mutually (re)define commands. There is not really a good solution for this as far as I know, just be careful with your command names and hope for the best :)

Comment: It can cause real mayhem when two loaded packages try to use the same macro name for different things.  Avoid it like the plague.  Take @moewe's advice...choose macro names so unique that no other package would use that name.  That and use `@` as part of the name helps, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably thinking of a compiled or interpreted language where a function definition provides a local scope that hides the implementation from calling code. That idiom does not apply to a macro expansion language like TeX.

If your package defines a user command `\foo` in terms of some helper commands that are only relevant to internal package code, say

```
\newcommand\foo{zzz \internalfoohelper zzz}
```

Then when `\foo` is used in a document it just expands to  `zzz \internalfoohelper zzz`  so `\internalfoohelper` needs to be defined *at that point* you can not just define it locally in the package code.

The usual solution is to pick some unique prefix, so all internal commands for `longtable` start `\LT@...` for example.